# Remove empty, double qoutes, and separate by comma

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, angular-pipe

I this data that I need to clean up when displayed in table, here's the output

> "eer""rrr""dff"""""""""""

What I need to do is to remove empty, remove the double qoutes, and separate it with comma, something like

```
  err,rrr,dff
```

I tried

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
   name: 'pickups'
})
export class PickupPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, args?: any) {
      if (!value) {
          return null;
       } else {
         return value.replace(/"/g, ",");
     }
 }
}
```

Now to use

```
   <span *ngFor="let pickup of row.pickups">{{pickup.pickup_facility | pickups }}</span>
```

It does remove the qoutes and empty but doesnt separate with comma, here is the result

> eerrrrdff

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace all quotes with a comma and then replace any sequence of more than one comma with a single comma. This will lead to a comma in the beginning and end of the string, so you substring to drop those.

```js
let text = `"eer""rrr""dff"""""""""""`
let replaced = text.replace(/"/g, ',').replace(/,+/g, ',')
replaced = replaced.substring(1, replaced.length - 1)

console.log(replaced);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.  **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
const text = '"eer""rrr""dff"""""""""""'
const result = text.match(/"[^"]*"/g)
                   .map(x => x.slice(1, -1)) // remove quotes
                   .filter(Boolean) // remove empty
                   .join(',') // separate with comma
```

Comment: @rai Sorry, I don't know angular pipes. What are the values that are passed to `transform`, and what does the function need to return?

Comment: Pipes basically like a helper function, in this case called pickups. In es6, for example I have an array of object called row which contain pickups. inside pickups are value "eer","rrr","dff" and some empty values. So what I really need is that, when looping the results, I should appy the pickups functions so that 1. it will remove the empty values, 2. separate result values with comma. something like for(const a of row.pickups){result = a then; then result will call the pickups function}

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option

1. First comma separating all strings
2. Removing empty strings
3. Clearing initial and last double quotes
4. Removing last comma

```js
var test = '"eer""rrr""dff"""""""""""'
           .replace(/""/g,',')  //first comma separating all strings 
           .replace(/,,/g,'')   // removing empty strings
           .replace(/"/g,'')    // clearing initial and last double quotes
           .slice(0, -1);;      // removing last comma

console.log(test);
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/BxPpoB?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all sequences of `"` by coma and then remove colons from start and end:

```
const str = '"eer""rrr""dff"""""""""""'
const result = `"${str}"`.replace(/""*/g, ',').slice(1, -1)
```